# Asynctask in another class?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have a problem with the call of asyncTask....
i have a class named arrivi

```
public class arrivi extends Fragment {

ListView list;
int thread = 0;
public String[] lista = new String[200];


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   View ios = inflater.inflate(R.layout.arrivi, container, false); 
   new MyTask().execute("");

   return ios;
}

//INIZIO THREAD

public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
```

with new MyTask this work fine...
but i want call MyTask into MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

ViewPager Tab;
TabPagerAdapter TabAdapter;
ActionBar actionBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

.....
.....
i have tried to
arrivi a = new arrivi();
a.MyTask.execute("");
i don't know...
how to make a call?? can you make me an example of code?
Thank u guys!

Comment: new MyTask().execute(""); and make MyTask static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this, but what it looks like you are trying to do here is actually to make `MyTask` static:

`public static class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {`

and that way, in your activity, you can just call:

`new arrivi.MyTask().execute();`

(Optional) further explanation:

the other alternative is to use the syntax -

`new arrivi().new MyTask().execute();` which i think is what you could also be trying to accomplish.

given that you are calling your `MyTask` in two separate places, it seems you might as well either make your `MyTask` static OR place `MyTask` in its own class outside of both of these two classes (in order to syntactically make this correct. This, however, depends on if you want `MyTask` to interact with your fragment `arrivi`. For example, if, in your `onPostExecute()` of `MyTask`, you want to access something that `arrivi` has (such as a view), you probably want to place `MyTask` inside of `arrivi` still, and not use the `static` declaration

Comment: could you please poste up the code to your `onPreExecute()` of `MyTask` ? specifically the lines of crash where you try to use an Alert Dialog

Answer (score 0):

thank u for replies... in mainactivity i have this:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

ViewPager Tab;
TabPagerAdapter TabAdapter;
ActionBar actionBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    TabAdapter = new TabPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    Tab = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);

    Tab.setOnPageChangeListener(
    new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

    actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);                    }
    });
    Tab.setAdapter(TabAdapter);
    actionBar = getActionBar();

    //Enable Tabs on Action Bar
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener(){
    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
    FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        Tab.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }
    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
    };
    //Add New Tab
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Info").setTabListener(tabListener));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Arrivi").setTabListener(tabListener));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Partenze").setTabListener(tabListener));


    if (isOnline())  { 
        //System.out.println("CONNESSIONE OK");
        new arrivi().new MyTask().execute();    
        }else{

        try {
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();

            alertDialog.setTitle("Info");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Connessione Internet non disponibile.");
            alertDialog.setButton("Esci", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                }                       

            });
            alertDialog.show();
        }
        catch(Exception e) { }
    }
}
```

public boolean isOnline() {

```
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        return true;
    }    
    return false;
}
```

}

and this is arrivi class:

```
public class arrivi extends Fragment {

ListView list;
int thread = 0;
public String[] lista = new String[200];


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   View ios = inflater.inflate(R.layout.arrivi, container, false); 

   new MyTask().execute("");
   return ios;

}      

//INIZIO THREAD

public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    ProgressDialog prog;
    String info;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        prog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        prog.setMessage("Connessione in corso...");
        prog.show();
        prog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        prog.setCancelable(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {

            org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://site.eu").timeout(7*1000).get();

            org.jsoup.nodes.Element tabella = doc.getElementsByClass("tabella-voli").first();
            Iterator<org.jsoup.nodes.Element> iterator = tabella.select("td").iterator();

            while(iterator.hasNext()){
                thread++;

                lista[thread] = iterator.next().text();
                System.out.println("Posizione["+thread+"]"+lista[thread]); 
            }

         }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
           }

        return info;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) { 
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        prog.dismiss();

        CheckRow();
    }
}// FINE THREAD
```

but when i lunch my app, crashes and here there is a logcat
http://paste.ubuntu.com/7253904/
i think line 43 is NULL...             prog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
..thank you so much guys!!